# Post data with libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

I've problem with libcurl. I wrote simple program which should post data (fill the form) but program's not working.
My form:

```
...
<div><label for="id_person_name">Your name</label> <input type="text" id="id_person_name" name="name" /></div>
            <div></div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div><label for="id_comment">Comment</label><textarea name="comment" id="id_comment" rows="10" cols="60" class="txt"></textarea></div>
...
```

Program:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl) {
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://examplesite.com");
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=Bjarne&comment=example");
res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

cout << endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Of course i tested this code: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postit2.html but it's not working.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Could you please define "not working", it connects for me

Comment: So I show you simple example. I use http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html this program and i test it on this page: m.se.pl/n-c/comments/dodaj/27/269110/ i fill the address 
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://m.se.pl/n-c/comments/dodaj/27/269110/");`and 
 `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=test&comment=test");` and compile it - everything is ok. I start my program, after 5 sec. program show me source this page (of course source code before adding the post).

Comment: On webpage you provide you need also to include some extra information to form post like: security_hash, timesamp, next, etc (they are hidden fields).you can see them in webpage source code. I suppose that this makes server reject query causing no webpage return

Comment: Good point, I have only one question. In source code i see i.e. 
`<input type="hidden" name="content_type_id" value="27">` how i should use CURL:
`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "content_type_id=27&name=test...);` ?

Comment: yes, all hidden and visible fields, altho, some might be generated on the server side, hance first you need to fetch this page and parse it correctly

Comment: Thanks a lot. I generated simple form and everything is ok.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to set `CURLOPT_URL` to address which `<form>` points, as shown [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html), for example.

The code from the above link is:

```
/***************************************************************************
 *                                  _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1998 - 2015, Daniel Stenberg, <daniel@haxx.se>, et al.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution. The terms
 * are also available at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html.
 *
 * You may opt to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, under the terms of the COPYING file.
 *
 * This software is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/ 
/* <DESC>
 * simple HTTP POST using the easy interface
 * </DESC>
 */ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */ 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://postit.example.com/moo.cgi");
    /* Now specify the POST data */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=daniel&project=curl");

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I checked this: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html
but it didn't send my data. Any suggestion ?

Comment: looks like you missed curl_global_init

Comment: I didn't miss curl_global_init. Example which I use (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html) contain it. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: it's a small but remarkable error here. add `curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POST,1L);` before setting post data. It is presented in question but missing in solution